# vdbench what is the parameter for controlling the queue depth?

Tags: io

How can we control the queue depth of vdbench? I am looking for a input parameter corresponding to queue depth but am unable to locate so. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look for the threads= parameter.
For further questions, please look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vdbench-downloads-1901681.html

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Are you the author of the benchmark? Thanks